# What is a ESD tube?

Tags: esp8266, esd, tube

In the ESP32 datasheet, what do they refer to with "ESD tube"?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESD stands for ElectroStatic Discharge, an "ESD Tube" is used to protect the part against damage caused by static discharges which produce much larger voltages than the part can take. Also look at TVS diodes.

Here's a selection:

https://eu.mouser.com/Circuit-Protection/ESD-Suppressors-TVS-Diodes/_/N-jy72?P=1z1412j

It's essentially a diode with a breakdown voltage lower than the voltage which would cause damage to the part but higher than the supply voltage. So when an overvoltage appears on the supply line the diode shunts it to ground. These devices are used to absorb spikes and shouldn't be used to continuously regulate a DC supply.

Comment: Why are they called ESD _tubes_ specifically? Are they referring to GDTs?

Comment: Haven't a clue. Maybe :)

Comment: ESD tube could be a GDT (Gas discharge Tube), rather slow compared to the semiconductor parts but very robust. I use them routinely on antenna lines coming in from the tower and on power lines where they may have run overhead and thus been exposed to EFT.

Answer (score 1):

Tube is just the packaging type of the ESD diode arrays. It just means there's multiple ESD diodes in one package/chip usually with a common ground, similar to a resistor array.

If you look at the schematic for their DevKitC V4 board you can see they heeded their own advice and used 3 ESD diodes on the USB input data/power port. This is where the "tube"/array packaged ESD diodes would come in handy.